# how to use ng2 search filter in primeng table

Tags: html, angular, typescript, primeng

I want to display table data when I change the dropdown value. As an example, if I change the rank dropdown value to 'A' then the table should display only rank A data. Currently, I'm using angular priming Material. Before I got the problem table data doubling error and after I resolve that using 'let-pjt' then I could not use the "ng2 search filter" option.

**component.html**

```
 <div class="col">
                    <p-dropdown [options]="rankArr" name="rank" [(ngModel)]="project.rank" optionLabel="rank" optionValue="rank" [style]="{'width':'100%'}" placeholder="{{'placeholder.rank' | translate}}"></p-dropdown>
                </div>

<div class="table" style="margin-right: 15px; overflow-x:auto;">
            <p-table [value]="projects" styleClass="p-datatable-gridlines" responsiveLayout="scroll" scrollHeight="17.8vw">
                <ng-template pTemplate="header">
                    <tr>
                        <th style="text-align: center;" translate>itemlist.customer <br> itemlist.name</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center;" translate>itemlist.project <br> itemlist.name</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center;" translate>itemlist.business <br> itemlist.divition</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center;" translate>itemlist.rank</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center;" translate>itemlist.order <br> itemlist.amount</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center;" translate>itemlist.customer <br> itemlist.area</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center;" translate>itemlist.sales <br> itemlist.incharge</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center;" translate>itemlist.incharge<br> itemlist.pm</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center;" translate>itemlist.incharge<br> itemlist.pl</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center;" translate>itemlist.update <br> itemlist.date</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center;" translate>itemlist.updater</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center;" translate>itemlist.process</th>
                    </tr>
                </ng-template>
                <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-pjt> 
                    <tr>

                        <td style="text-align: center;">{{ pjt.customer_name }}</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center; width: 15vw;">{{ pjt.project_name_jp }}</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">{{ pjt.business_divition }}</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">{{ pjt.rank }}</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">{{ pjt.order_amount }}</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">{{ pjt.customer_area }}</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">{{ pjt.sales_in_charge }}</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">{{ pjt.in_charge_pm }}</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">{{ pjt.in_charge_pl }}</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">{{ pjt.updated_at }}</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">{{ pjt.updated_by }}</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center; width: 70vw;">
                            <button pButton pRipple routerLink="item-register/{{ pjt.id }}" type="button" class="p-button-outlined p-button-secondary" translate>itemlist.actual <br> itemlist.input</button>&nbsp;
                            <button pButton pRipple type="button" translate="itemlist.duplicate" class="p-button-outlined"></button> &nbsp;
                            <button pButton pRipple (click)="deleteProject(pjt.id)" type="button" translate="itemlist.delete" class="p-button-outlined p-button-danger"></button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ng-template>
            </p-table>
```

before I could search using the below code but the table data was doubling.

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" > 
                    <tr *ngFor="let pjt of projects | filter:project.rank | filter:project.business_divition | filter:project.in_charge_area 
                    | filter:project.customer_area | filter:project.in_charge_pm | filter:project.in_charge_pl | filter:project.sales_in_charge
                    | filter:project.updated_by | filter:project.customer_name">

                        <td style="text-align: center;">{{ pjt.customer_name }}</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center; width: 15vw;">{{ pjt.project_name_jp }}</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">{{ pjt.business_divition }}</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">{{ pjt.rank }}</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">{{ pjt.order_amount }}</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">{{ pjt.customer_area }}</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">{{ pjt.sales_in_charge }}</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">{{ pjt.in_charge_pm }}</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">{{ pjt.in_charge_pl }}</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">{{ pjt.updated_at }}</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">{{ pjt.updated_by }}</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center; width: 70vw;">
                            <button pButton pRipple routerLink="item-register/{{ pjt.id }}" type="button" class="p-button-outlined p-button-secondary" translate>itemlist.actual <br> itemlist.input</button>&nbsp;
                            <button pButton pRipple type="button" translate="itemlist.duplicate" class="p-button-outlined"></button> &nbsp;
                            <button pButton pRipple (click)="deleteProject(pjt.id)" type="button" translate="itemlist.delete" class="p-button-outlined p-button-danger"></button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ng-template>
```

Comment: From my concern, using *ng2-search-filter* pipe will filter all the columns that contain the parsed value. Does your desired answer is to search value in a specified column (example: rank value to search rank column only) or to search value for all columns (rank value so search all columns)?

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Yong_Shun 
Actually, I want to filter table data using three dropdowns. Dropdowns are out of the table but on the same page.

Comment: If you keen on these multiple filter pipes, then move those pipes to  `<p-table [value]="projects | filter:project.rank | filter:project.business_divition | filter:project.in_charge_area | filter:project.customer_area | filter:project.in_charge_pm | filter:project.in_charge_pl | filter:project.sales_in_charge | filter:project.updated_by | filter:project.customer_name"`></p-table>.

Comment: See this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ktduze?file=src%2Fapp%2Fitem-list%2Fitem-list.component.html)

Comment: but it is not working properly. Only rank B work. @yong-shun

Comment: Yes, this is why what I had said in the **first comment**. This filter pipe will be based on parsed value to **search all the properties (columns)**. As 'B' character only exists in Rank column, so it works. While 'A', 'C', 'D' characters existed in different columns, so those rows contains the character will be filtered.

Comment: I got it now. thank you so much. Can you give suggestions for this?

Comment: I tried to do using this https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/table/filter

Answer (score 0):

Actually in your case, i often split the filter or business code to typescript component and try to keep template as clean as possible.

So i will use the function with context object to query/filter the list trojects.

```
let filterObj = {
 rank: '',....
};
getProjects(){
 return projects.filter(e=> e.rank == filterObj.rank);
}
```

Then for dropdown box, i will add event onChange to apply new rank of filterObj.

```
onChangeRank(e){
  this.filterObj.rank = e;
}
```

So in template will be more simpler:

```
<tr *ngFor="let pjt of getProjects()">
```